# How to compile LD_PRELOAD for most systems

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, ld-preload

I Have a LD_PRELOAD file. On what OS and conditions i should compile this preload to work on most systems (Unix/Linux). The most wanted are FreeBSD, Ubuntu, CenstOS, Solaris.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile it into a shared library. Here's how I typically compile mine:

```
libt.so: t.lo
        g++ -fPIC -O3 -W -Wall -shared -Wl,-export-dynamic -o $@ $^ -lc

t.lo: t.cc
        g++ -c -fPIC -O3 -W -Wall $^ -o $@
```

Then to use it, you add the library to the LD_PRELOAD environment variable before launching that file. If you do it this way from the `bash` command line:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libt.so executable_name -and args
```

then, it will only set it for that command line run, and not affect any other programs you launch afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can i give me a full makefile, because when i use yours i catch error *** missing separator . My source file name - test.cpp

Comment: @Robert: need tab instead of spaces in front of `g++`. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. DO i need to always copy t.lo with libt.so or i can use only libt.so?

Comment: @Robert: just the `.so` file. Regards.

Comment: Thanks, last question :). Will this .so file work on x32 and x64 OS like Solaris, FreeBSD, Ubuntu, CentOs without recompile? Can i compile it on Ubuntu server x64 and use compiled .so file on all systems and architectures above?  Thanks!

Comment: @Robert: You need to recompile on each one. It is possible to run binaries across systems, but requires ABI compatibility libraries installed. And I am not sure about executing 64bit binary on 32bit binary, so if you are going for ABI compatibility, you would need to compile 32bit. I think compiling a different binary for each system is a much better solution.

Comment: so i can move `t.lo` to each one os and compile libt.so from it, without copying sources to each one os?

Comment: @Robert: You will need to recompile the source for each platform. Regards.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please give me a link to some information how to convert my library to ABI compatible library?

Comment: It is not a fully solved problem, but you can see [this](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/linux-emulation/index.html) to see what you are getting into.

Comment: Thanks! I will compile it on each OS, is there a way to compile LD_PRELOAD for each platform without installing these platforms?

Comment: @Robert: I don't understand that question. You might possible want to post a different question at this point. Regards.